# Working with java and scala in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

Am working on a project, it contains both java and scala classes. 
My folder structure: is
`src>main>java` -> for java classes
`src>main>scala` -> for scala classes
When am importing scala classes in java, eclipse saying that no type found. I already installed scala IDE in eclipse. I don't know how to fix this problem. Can anyone help me with the configuration of eclipse to work with both java and scala?

Comment: How many source folders do you have in your project?

Comment: Are you using a Maven plugin already?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos total 3 including src/test/java.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ya.. There is no error in build time, i configured maven to build-first-scala. But i need help on configuring eclipse.

Comment: Does you project have a scala nature? Is src/main/scala in the build path?

Comment: @jny I think No. How do i set a project to have scala nature? Yes it is in build path. Thanks

Comment: If you have Scala IDE: Right Click on Project->Scala ->Add Scala Nature. However, if it is needed, if it is set as a Maven project

Comment: @jny I haven't found Scala option in project.

Comment: Try Right Click on Project->Configure ->Add Scala Nature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding scala nature to project, As told by @jny:

`Right click on Project -> Configure -> Add Scala Nature`